# Get user location latitude and longitude via telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

How to Get user location latitude and longitude via telegram bot?

Module: [Link](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)

**Code:**

```
bot.onText(/getLocation/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: [
        [{text: 'Location', request_location: true}],
        [{text: 'Contact', request_contact: true}],
      ],
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true,
    }),
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Contact and Location request', opts);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved ✔️

```
bot.on('location', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.location.latitude);
  console.log(msg.location.longitude);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bot.on('location', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.message.location.latitude);
  console.log(msg.message.location.longitude);
});
```